# Symfony 2 multi file upload embeded form in a another form

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload, embed

I have a file upload form embeded in an AdsList form and when submitted the adslist_id is null in the photos table when I allow the field to be null. But when I don't I get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Photos (photo_path,
thumbnail_path,adslist_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["louboutin-pigalle1.jpg",
null, null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'adslist_id' 
cannot be null
```

If you guys did not have a clue I would appreciate to pointed to a tutorial to upload multiple upload files embeded to an entity. This should be pretty standard but I am not able to find one.

This is my obbex/AdsBundle/Entity/AdsList

```
<?php

namespace obbex\AdsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AdsList
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsListRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class AdsList
{


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $telephone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="display_phone", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $displayPhone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $country;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="region", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $region;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="department", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $department;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zip_code", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $zipCode;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status_pro", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $statusPro;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="creationtime", type="datetime")
 */
private $creationtime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updatetime", type="datetime")
 */
private $updatetime;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="publication", type="boolean")
 */
private $publication;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos",mappedBy="adslist", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $photos;

/**
 * Set photos
 *
 * @param \obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setPhotos(\obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos = null)
{
    $this->photos = $photos;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get photos
 *
 * @return \obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos 
 */
public function getPhotos()
{
    return $this->photos;
}

public function __construct() {
    $this->creationtime=new \Datetime;
    $this->photos = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set telephone
 *
 * @param string $telephone
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setTelephone($telephone)
{
    $this->telephone = $telephone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get telephone
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTelephone()
{
    return $this->telephone;
}

/**
 * Set displayPhone
 *
 * @param string $displayPhone
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setDisplayPhone($displayPhone)
{
    $this->displayPhone = $displayPhone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get displayPhone
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDisplayPhone()
{
    return $this->displayPhone;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}

/**
 * Set region
 *
 * @param string $region
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setRegion($region)
{
    $this->region = $region;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get region
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getRegion()
{
    return $this->region;
}

/**
 * Set department
 *
 * @param string $department
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setDepartment($department)
{
    $this->department = $department;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get department
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDepartment()
{
    return $this->department;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param string $address
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set city
 *
 * @param string $city
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setCity($city)
{
    $this->city = $city;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city;
}

/**
 * Set zipCode
 *
 * @param string $zipCode
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setZipCode($zipCode)
{
    $this->zipCode = $zipCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get zipCode
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getZipCode()
{
    return $this->zipCode;
}

/**
 * Set statusPro
 *
 * @param string $statusPro
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function setStatusPro($statusPro)
{
    $this->statusPro = $statusPro;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Get statusPro
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getStatusPro()
{
    return $this->statusPro;
}

/**
 * Set creationtime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $creationtime
 * @return test
 */
public function setCreationtime($creationtime)
{
    $this->creationtime = $creationtime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get creationtime
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreationtime()
{
    return $this->creationtime;
}

/**
 * Set updatetime
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatetime
 * @return Test
 */
public function setUpdatetime($updatetime)
{
    $this->updatetime = $updatetime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatetime
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getUpdatetime()
{
    return $this->updatetime;
}

/**
 * Set publication
 *
 * @param boolean $publication
 * @return test
 */
public function setPublication($publication)
{
    $this->publication = $publication;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get publication
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getPublication()
{
    return $this->publication;
}

// Callback
/**
* @ORM\PreUpdate
*/  
public function udpateDate()
{
     $this->setUpdatetime(new \DateTime());
}

/**
 * Add photos
 *
 * @param \obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos
 * @return AdsList
 */
public function addPhoto(\obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos)
{
    $this->photos[] = $photos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove photos
 *
 * @param \obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos
 */
public function removePhoto(\obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos)
{
    $this->photos->removeElement($photos);
}
```

}

And this is the obbex/AdsBundle/Entity/Photos class:

```
<?php

namespace obbex\AdsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Photos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\PhotosRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Photos
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList", inversedBy="photos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="adslist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $adslist;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo_path", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $photoPath;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail_path", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $thumbnailPath;

private $file;

private $tempFilename;

public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $this->file = $file;

    if (null !== $this->photoPath) {
      $this->tempFilename = $this->photoPath;
      // reset values
    }
}

public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set photoPath
 *
 * @param string $photoPath
 * @return Photos
 */
public function setPhotoPath($photoPath)
{
    $this->photoPath = $photoPath;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get photoPath
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPhotoPath()
{
    return $this->photoPath;
}

/**
 * Set thumbnailPath
 *
 * @param string $thumbnailPath
 * @return Photos
 */
public function setThumbnailPath($thumbnailPath)
{
    $this->thumbnailPath = $thumbnailPath;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get thumbnailPath
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getThumbnailPath()
{
    return $this->thumbnailPath;
}

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if($this->file === null){
        return;
    }

    //$this->extension = $this->file->guessExtention();  // In my case I don't need it
    $this->photoPath = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
}


/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if($this->file === null){
        return;
    }

    if(null !== $this->tempFilename)
    {
        $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempFilename;
        if(file_exists($oldFile)){
            unlink($oldFile);
        }
    }


    $this->file->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id.'.'.$this->photoPath
    );
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function PreRemoveUpload()
{        
    $this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.''.$this->photoPath;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if(filex_exists($this->tempFilename))
    {
        unlink($this->tempFilename);
    }
}

public function getUploadDir()
{
    return '/upload/img';
}

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->getPhotoPath();
}

public function getMyWebPath()
{
    return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getPhotoPath();
}

/**
 * Set adslist
 *
 * @param \obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList $adslist
 * @return Photos
 */
public function setAdslist(\obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList $adslist = null)
{
    $this->adslist = $adslist;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adslist
 *
 * @return \obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\AdsList 
 */
public function getAdslist()
{
    return $this->adslist;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this in the addPhotos method:

```
public function addPhoto(\obbex\AdsBundle\Entity\Photos $photos)
{
    $this->photos[] = $photos;

    $photos->setAdslist($this); // I added this line, now the photo adslist_id is correctly set

    return $this;
}
```